# How can I change disk cache path in PhantomJS?

Tags: caching, phantomjs

I want to change disk cache directory path for **PhantomJS**. It's required for my product.

When I'm using `--disk-cache=true --max-disk-cache-size=1024` option in phantomJS command line.

It works perfectly. But cache is saved to this below directory. I want to change it to my specified directory.

`C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Ofi Labs\PhantomJS` to `my_dir`

Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 1):

This seems only possible by compiling the code yourself with the necessary changes.

The method `writableLocation` in the file [qstandardpaths_win.cpp](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/src/qt/qtbase/src/corelib/io/qstandardpaths_win.cpp) handles the paths. There you can set your own path and compile it for your platform.

I suggest to implement it dynamically to add a command line flag for this and create a pull request so that it will be merged back into the project. I see you already opened an issue [there](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12454).

Answer (score 1):

It has been implemented recently, and in phantomjs v2.1.1 or newer you can use **--disk-cache-path**=...

https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/commit/c9e30ebafdeb42efe33900da7823142e146b0a1d